# Multiple IF Clauses - DAX

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, dax

I am attempting to get my formula to read from another column in DAX, basically checking if certain numbers in it match the expectations in the **IF** statement, then to output a certain plant. I have used the below formula, and it is making everything **Main Plant.**

```
Shop v2 = 
IF([Department] = "200" || "201" || "202" || "203" || "205" || "206" || "207", "Main Plant", 
        IF([Department] = "250" || "254", "Mt. Athos Plant",
            IF([Department] = "300" || "301" || "302" || "303" || "305" || "306" || "307", "South Plant",
                IF(mid(trim([Account]),4,3) = "600" || "601" || "602" || "603" || "604" || "605" || "606" || "607", "Rock Hill Plant", "Not Available"))))
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

Fix your OR conditions with IN [Department] in {"200","201","202"...}